# Fantasy isekai manga; young protagonist with the ability to echo any spell he'd heard before

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The protagonist starts out young and ends up travelling with some adventurers. One of the team is a younger girl that's close to the MC's age and together they learn a bit about magic. I think everyone in the world had some unique skill and the MC's ability was something *echolalia/echolala* or something like that. It allowed him to essentially cast a duplicate spell without using any of the MCs mana, could be his spell, could be another persons spell.

Overall the power scale is pretty reasonable, not like god-killing levels like a lot of isekai have. Truth be told, I don't remember if this one is technically an "isekai" or if it's just a fantasy-based sword-and-magic manga.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You say "a long time ago" but could you be more specific about approximate when you read this?  Last year?  2015?  Also, do you have any idea what site you might have read it on?

Comment: @DavidW I updated it to say the last few years for timeline of when I've read it but Im finding more and more that these mangas are highly varied on when they came out. I found some that I've read more recently only to find they update maybe twice a year, so they've been going since 2015-16. I dont remember if either of these were being actively updated when I read them last. Plus life seems like a blur, I feel like I read a bit of these months ago but it could very well have been two or more years at this point.

Comment: If you think you're asking about two separate manga, please edit this post to ask about one of them only, and then ask about the other one in a separate post. Otherwise, this question will likely be closed on the grounds of being insufficiently focused, as we prefer each story-ID question to ask about a single story.

Comment: @LogicDictates the reason I have them both here is that I cant rule out that they arent the same manga. I cant remember how one starts, and I dont remember how overpowered the the other manga protag is. Its been a while and they very well could be the same manga but I just have a faulty memory.

Comment: https://myanimelist.net/anime/52611/Okashi_na_Tensei is an Isekai manga with a reborn character who can replicate spells.